# How do I force tf.variable_scope to reuse name_scope?

Tags: tensorflow

```
with tf.variable_scope('aa') as sa:
    with tf.variable_scope('bb'):
        x =  tf.get_variable(
            'biases', (2,),
            initializer=tf.constant_initializer()
        )
        y1 = tf.identity(x, name='bb')
with tf.variable_scope(sa):
    with tf.variable_scope('cc'):
        x =  tf.get_variable(
            'biases', (2,),
            initializer=tf.constant_initializer()
        )
        y2 = tf.identity(x, name='cc')
```

I entered the `tf.variable_scope('aa')` twice, and generated 2 tensors `y1`, `y2`.

However, `y2.name == 'aa_1/cc/cc:0'`.  (`y1.name == 'aa/bb/bb:0'`)

Is it possible to make `y2.name == 'aa/cc/cc:0'` instead?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little late, but try to add a `/` at the end of the namescope to explicitly indicate you want to reuse the scope. Otherwise, as you noticed, it add a `_1`. I had a similar problem with `name_scope` but I think the solution works with `variable_scope` too.

```python
with tf.variable_scope('aa/'):
    ... # Some initialisation
with tf.variable_scope('aa/'):
    ... # Reuse the name scope
```