# How does reuse option in tf.variable_scope work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, with-statement

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf

def _var_init(name, shape, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
              trainable=True):
  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    var = tf.get_variable(
      name=name,
      shape=shape,
      initializer=initializer,
      trainable=trainable
    )
    return var

def main():
  sess = tf.Session()

  # 1th case, it works
  with tf.variable_scope('test1', reuse=False) as test1:
    with tf.variable_scope('test2', reuse=False) as test2:
      w1 = _var_init('w1', [1, 2])
      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      print(sess.run(w1), w1)

  # 2th case, it works
  with tf.variable_scope('test1', reuse=True):
    with tf.variable_scope('test2', reuse=False):
      w2 = _var_init('w1', [1, 2])
      print(sess.run(w2), w2)

  # 3th case, it works
  with tf.variable_scope(test1, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope(test2, reuse=True):
      w3 = _var_init('w1', [1, 2])
      print(sess.run(w3), w3)

  # 4th case, ValueError: Variable test1/test2/w1 already exists.
  with tf.variable_scope(test1, reuse=True):
    with tf.variable_scope(test2, reuse=False):
      w4 = _var_init('w1', [1, 2])
      print(sess.run(w4), w4)

  # 5th case, ValueError: Variable test1/test2/w1 already exists.
  with tf.variable_scope('test1', reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('test2', reuse=False):
      w5 = _var_init('w1', [1, 2])
      print(sess.run(w5), w5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

1th-3th case outputs:

```
[[ 0.34345531 -0.84748644]] <tf.Variable 'test1/test2/w1:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32_ref>
[[ 0.34345531 -0.84748644]] <tf.Variable 'test1/test2/w1:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32_ref>
[[ 0.34345531 -0.84748644]] <tf.Variable 'test1/test2/w1:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32_ref>
```

Question:

I'm confused why 2th case works but 4th fail. Doesn't Tensorflow search variable_scope by scope_name?  What's difference between 2th case and 4th case? (i.e. what's the difference between `with tf.variable_scope('test1', reuse=True):` and `with tf.variable_scope(test1, reuse=False):`?)

I think they are same before. But now they looks different. How does reuse option in tf.variable_scope work?

Similar but not duplicated Question：

1. [How does the reuse option in tf.variable_scope work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234110/how-does-the-reuse-option-in-tf-variable-scope-work)
   ;
2. [How do I force tf.variable_scope to reuse name_scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488054/how-do-i-force-tf-variable-scope-to-reuse-name-scope)

Answer (score 2):

From the official documentation of Tensorflow this is all that explains the reuse option:

This is a basic example of sharing a variable:

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
     v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):
     v1 = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
assert v1 == v
```

Sharing a variable by capturing a scope and setting reuse:

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo") as scope:
    v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
    scope.reuse_variables()
    v1 = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
assert v1 == v
```

Similarly, we raise an exception when trying to get a variable that does not exist in reuse mode.

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):
    v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
    #  Raises ValueError("... v does not exists ...").
```

Note that the reuse flag is inherited: if we open a reusing scope, then all its sub-scopes become reusing as well.

A note about name scoping: Setting reuse does not impact the naming of other ops such as mult. See related discussion on github#6189

Note that up to and including version 1.0, it was allowed (though explicitly discouraged) to pass False to the reuse argument, yielding undocumented behaviour slightly different from None. Starting at 1.1.0 passing None and False as reuse has exactly the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I notice you say "ote that the reuse flag is inherited:.....as well". In fact, reuse option in `test1` scope doesn't control its sub-scope `test2` reuse option. As you saying, `test2` scope should  inherit  reuse option in `test1` scope and ignore its own reuse option. If that, 3-th case will occur ValueError(' w is already existed'). To the contrary, 3-th case works and 4-th case is wrong. I think reusing depend on its own reuse option, not its parent scope. But 2th case works, it looks that reusing don't depend on its own reuse option but its parent scope reuse option

Comment: That's why I'm confused about it. And I read github#6189, their question is different. In my case, all `w` value has same name and value, it's reusing. I'm still confused about 2th case and 4-th case. Their only difference is that 2th case get variable sope by string but 4th case get variable scope by variable. But the name of `test1` variable_scope is 'test1', what's the influence of this way?